# What is a weight limit of stepper motor?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

I'm going to buy a stepper motor Nema 17 SL42STH34-1504A with this parameters:

```
Rated Current: 1.7A
17 SL42STH34-1504A
Rated Voltage: 3.57V
```

I will use it with 12V 1.8A charger and I would like to know (probably) how heavy object with wheels attached to 2meters long stepper belt I will be able to move from A to B in ideal world (without outside factors)

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of *torque* ? In any case, your information is insufficient. If the belt is horizontal, in *ideal* world without friction and other parasitic forces the weight limit  would be infinite.

Comment: Are you familiar with the difference between velocity and acceleration? Is the limitation going to be friction on the masses, or the acceleration of their mass. A ramping rather than on/off speed control for the stepper will allow higher speeds and accelerations.

Comment: it is horizontal, I mean, "probably" like 15cm long, 100g heavy wood-made cart model with 4 wheel moving on a floor. Will the motor be able to move more than 2 kg without struggle?

Comment: You really need to describe (draw) your full mechanical system. It all depends on: Gearing, if exists, shaft sizes, required acceleration and velocity.

Comment: Your motor would be able to move tonnes, with a suitable gearbox, but very verrrrrry slowly. How fast do you want to move your loads?

Comment: 1 meter(half of the stepper belt) in two minutes, is it realistic?

Comment: only if you choose the right belt pulley ratio and correct acceleration step rate

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think Marcel is trying to design that system.

Comment: @MarcelKopera Do you want it to move sideways or up down? It matters because if you move up and down, then the motor has to fight gravity

Comment: This question belongs on the general [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions) stack. It has little to do with *Electrical* Engineering.

Comment: also, I'm almost sure I've seen similar questions multiple times – I think with the terms supplied in the comments here and your research on them you could ask a much more precise question over at Engineering.

Comment: I Googled your motor and it's about $10 to $15. Unless you're a poor kid or poor college student, I recommend you just buy one and play with it a bit!

Comment: thanks for all your comments, I just try to buy one and test it

Answer (score 1):

Choosing the right motor and pulley gears to match the performance you need is like choosing a motor for any vehicle, except out of 5 gears, you can pick only 1 for torque vs maximum speed tradeoffs.

-so estimate the min. linear speed you need and get pulleys over and under then ensure you limit acceleration in full steps.