# What DC motor is suitable to push and pull 60 kg load system with wheels?

Tags: dc-motor, stepper-motor, component-selection

I have a projector system with a PS4 and other electronic devices that I put on a small shelf cabinet with wheels. In normal status it will stay inside the space under my wardrobe.  When I need to use the projector,  I need it to move in front of the wardrobe (distance around 60 cm) because my projector screen pulls down from the ceiling in front of the wardrobe.

To make the process easier and more convenient, I am thinking of using a motor for it with an IR remote control (designing the remote control will be investigated separately) to press a button, so it will push the system out to the desired position, then press button once and it will go back to its station (60cm depth.)

I believe the motor will not need to be very large because I have an electric skateboard that can push me around (over 60kg) without any issue. The motor and battery are quite small.

How could I choose the right motor for the above requirement and make sure it can push the system? There will be another 4 wheels on the side to support the system.

Comment: First figure out what force you require to achieve your desired acceleration rate. That's what will determine the motor size - not running at constant speed. If you have a luggage scales it should be quite easy; just pull the load using the scales and take a reading. If not you could use a bathroom scales with a bit of trickery. Your measurement will be in kg. Multiply by 9.81 to convert to newtons (N).

Comment: Not a duplicate, but every comment is relevant for this question too: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574793/what-is-a-weight-limit-of-stepper-motor

Comment: Most motors will have a rates speed of at least 1000 RPM and likely several 1000 RPM. Converting that speed to a relatively slow linear motion will require a mechanism that is likely to have friction high enough to absorb as much torque as is required for acceleration. Look for motors that have a built-in speed-reduction gear. The motor literature should specify the torque available at the output of the attached gear,

Comment: Try pulling the load with your skateboard, look at the specs of the motor on that, and from there you can determine if you need to go higher or lower.

Comment: If the slide moves easily it could be moved by a small 12V gear motor, like something that would be used for a small robot’s wheel drive. Figure something in the 20-50W range and geared for 50-100RPM or so.

Comment: Nearly all of this question depends on mechanical engineering issues, not electrical ones.  Gearing, speed vs. torque, how much resistance your cart will see while plowing through purple shag carpet -- all of these are mechanical engineering issues, not electrical ones.  So -- this may be a better fit for engineering.stackexchange.com, at least until you know what torque and speed you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The motor must produce at least enough power to drive the linear load as desired and then some extra power to absorbed by the inertia and friction of the rotational to linear drive-line. Perhaps the best way to gain insight into the power necessary for driving a linear load is to simulate the system as a circuit by applying the the force-current analog. This is shown below as a current source (analog of force) charging a capacitor (analog of mass). The voltage on the grounded capacitor is the analog of velocity. The math block is an integrator and represents the position as integral of velocity. The CSV data to simulate driving force would be an estimate of the type of force produced by the motor. For example a PMDC motor coupled to a drive-line produces a force that starts at the maximum value and decays exponentially according to the motor time constant. The faster you want to accelerate the 60kg load the more power it will take because linear power is force times velocity and force is mass times acceleration. If you don't profile the power to drive the linear load then you are only building a system and observing the performance rather than designing the system to your specification.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDJyjb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A full circuit simulation of the motor and mechanical system is also possible using controlled sources to simulate the motor air gap and transformer to simulate the drive-line. However the point here is that the specification of motor and its power source depend on the mechanical power necessary to drive the load according to performance criteria. So there is no direct answer to the question.

Comment: this is an interesting simulation and explanation. If could not give direct answer to this question, can we come to a rough estimation (range) of the specs for the motor ? Is there any other parameters I could put in details so we could have better estimation ? And how about IR remote control part ?

Comment: @user1314404 - Hi, "*And how about IR remote control part ?*" As I tried to explain in the chat on your [previous question](/questions/575682), while you could mention your plan of eventually doing IR remote control here, you cannot include questions on *that* topic as part of *this* question. Otherwise, just like your previous question, you would make this question "too broad" and risk this one being closed too. So as it doesn't affect this motor specification question, I'm removing the IR remote control topic from here. Ask about that separately, when you decided about the motors. Thanks.

Comment: Ok Sam, tks for your reminder, agreed with your suggested plan.

Answer (score 0):

I made an [electric vehicle calculator](http://enginuitysystems.com/EVCalculator.htm) that might help you determine the size motor required. It's overkill for this application, as there is no need to factor in aerodynamic drag and other considerations, but it does provide calculations for thrust, torque, speed, acceleration, and power.

A couple years ago I got a kids' ride-on tractor that had 12 VDC motors that had failed, and I was surprised at the small size of the motors. They are the [industry standard RS-555](https://www.foneacc-motion.com/Product/RS-555-Small-DC-Motor.html), which may be as little as 15 watts at rated load. They are high speed (7000 RPM), so need to be geared down maybe 50:1 to drive the wheels at about 140 RPM. The toy tractor had two speeds, with two motors wired in series or parallel to the 12V battery.

To get an idea of the reduction gears, here are some pictures of the beast:

[image: Reduction gears]

[image: RS-555 motor]

Complete drive wheel sets are available for cheap on most robotics and R/C vehicle supplier websites, but you might also find what you need for free as I did. And another possibility would be battery powered drills, which have nice planetary reduction drives with lots of torque and adjustable speed.